# How to color Grid cells in Grid View?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagrid, datagridview

Below is my code and I have been trying to color the cells but not sure how to use the "Style" property when my source for grid is a DB. I am new to this so having difficulties getting started.

Some website or pointers would help a lot.

I want to be able to color some background cells or also color some rows or specific columns...Basically everything color related. How can I do this with my current snippet? Also a link to where I can learn more would be appreciated.

LarsTech I am trying to add you to a chat but I dont have enough rep so I think I can't contact you due to that.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim connectionString As String = "data source=SQst; database=MVar2; User ID=Wepp; Password=2010Live; Integrated Security=false;"

        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Prer"

        Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)

        Dim dataadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)

        Dim ds As New DataSet()

        connection.Open()

        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Authors_table")

        connection.Close()

        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds

        DataGridView1.DataMember = "Authors_table"
    **DataGridView1.Rows[2].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.PaleGreen
    DataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Red**    

    End Sub



    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Call PrintDGV.Print_DataGridView(DataGridView1)

    End Sub





End Class
```

**Errors I get:**

```
Error   1   Property access must assign to the property or use its value.   
Error   2   Identifier expected.    
Error   3   Property access must assign to the property or use its value.   
Error   4   Identifier expected.
```

I tried:
        DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cell(0).Style.BackColor = Color.Red

and I got 1 error:

```
Error   1   'Cell' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow'.
```

**EDIT**: After looking more around the web I got to color selected cells using below code:

```
DataGridView1.Item(4, 5).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
```

This however doesn't color rows or columns so I am still looking to make those things work.

Comment: Please see my revised answer. I didn't pay attention to the fact you were using VB and not c#. I added two more that will recolor entire columns and row. Using those two along with the code you found should be all you need to color your DGV to your hearts content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different ways of doing this. I beliebe that currentcell refers to the current active cell, so coloring based on that after filling your grid will yield no results.

A few ways to do this are:

```
c#:
For rows/cells:
dataGridView1.Rows[RowNumber].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.PaleGreen;
dataGridView1.Rows[RowNumber].Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;

for columns:
dataGridView1.Columns[ColumnNumber].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Black;


VB:
DataGridView1.Rows(0).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green
DataGridView1.Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue
```

Both of these will apply color to the cell background. Use some logic in order to control how/which cells/rows are being colored.

Comment: This is how I do it with my DGVs. Additionally, if you want to clear the color to go back to whatever the default system theme is (i.e. in most cases white), use `Color.Empty`

Comment: @Lee Harrison I tried this and I get a bunch of errors, I added new stuff and updated the code above.

Comment: @MichaelKarien what errors are you getting? Try calling `DataGridView1.Refresh()` to redraw the table after changing colors. It might also be that you're using `CurrentCell` although I'm not sure why that would affect anything. I'm looking at my code right now and I call it like (VB code)`myDGV.Rows(myDGV.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(4).Style.BackColor = Color.LightBlue` and then do `myDGV.Refresh` and that works.

Comment: His errors were due to the fact he directly pasted my c# code into the code window without changing the square braces into the correct VB parenthesis.

Comment: Thank you guys! It works now! Yeah I was suspecting that was C# since you had the ";" at the line ends

Answer (score 0):

You can also set this declaritively in the .aspx file. The link is to a 2.0 version of the code, but this is still compatible.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx)